# Detect browser version using LESS

Tags: javascript, css, less

Hello guys it is possible to detect browser version using less for example I have some less code that I don't want to be loaded on IE8 browser and I have discovered less guards that seems to be what I need but my problem is how to detect browser from less in order to set guard param true or false.

http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature

```
.my-optional-style() when (@my-option = true) {
  button {
    color: white;
  }
}
.my-optional-style()
```

;

Comment: Why not stick it in a file that is loaded within conditional comments in the HTML ?

Comment: Is it not better to use conditional comments? If you are pre-compiling the Less file to CSS before deploying then it would not at all be possible. Dynamic compilation in browser is not really recommended much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing as you have tagged Javascript I will provide the below - though note this is not a native LESS approach.

I wouldnt recommend browser targetting in this way vs conditional comments to load CSS or any other number of possible alternatives....however if you're determined, here you go:

Use the JS:

```
var b = document.documentElement;
        b.setAttribute('data-useragent',  navigator.userAgent);
        b.setAttribute('data-platform', navigator.platform );
        b.className += ((!!('ontouchstart' in window) || !!('onmsgesturechange' in window))?' touch':'');
```

To add e.g. the below to the `html` tag:

```
data-useragent='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)'
data-platform='Win32'
```

Allowing you to nest your LESS in e.g. (you will need to focus the rule, below is example only)

```
html:not([data-useragent*='IE/8']){
    // non IE8 styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always preferred using conditional comments to add classes on the `<html>` element approach to straight-up user agent sniffing. Conditional comments are only seen by Internet Explorer and ignored by other browsers, so the specified version(s) of IE are the only ones that get the class names. To me, the primary benefit is that you don't have to rely on Javascript.

It works a little like this:

**HTML:**

```
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

**LESS:**

```
.ie8 {
    .selector {
        color: red;
    }
 }
```

Nesting in LESS/Sass makes it easy to group all of your IE8 override styles in this case. You can read more about this approach here:

http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

And here's some more general information about conditional comments:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx